# Command Line Program - Sending 'Enter' commands

Tags: command-line, cmd

I have command line program that has a menu with multiple choice. I can pass the parameter via `program.exe < input.txt` but I am having problems sending the 'Enter' command (the program crashes if I attempt to send anything else; such as a ' ' character).

I enter 'All' as Proc name. It then prints 'enter proc name' again and I have to hit Enter for the code to continue. What I cannot work out is how to send this Enter to the program. I have tried a black line in input.txt but that did not work.

```c
while( !end )
{
    for( legal=0; !legal; )
    {
        printf("\tEnter Proc Name: ");

        if( fgets( str, 70, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            printf("Bye.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        ret = sscanf(str, "%s", p.name );
        if( ret > 0  || str[0] == '\n' ) legal = 1;
        else printf("Please enter a legal proc name, none, or all\n");
    }
    if( str[0] == '\n' ) {
        end = 1;
    } else if( !strcmp( p.name, "all" )) {
        for( i=0; i < Conf_num_procs( &Cn ); i++ )
            Status_vector[i] = 1;
    } else if( !strcmp( p.name, "none" )) {
        for( i=0; i < Conf_num_procs( &Cn ); i++ )
    Status_vector[i] = 0;
    } else {
        proc_index = Conf_proc_by_name( p.name, &p );
        if( proc_index != -1 ) {
            Status_vector[proc_index] = 1;
        } else printf("Please! enter a legal proc name, none, or all\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is program.exe compiled from your code? If so please post the relevant source.

Comment: No. It is not my code and I do not have the source code for it.

Comment: Then how do you expect anyone to explain its behaviour???

Comment: I can run it manually. By pressing 1 then return. I then have to hit return a 2nd time for the program to continue. I cannot seem to pass this return alone with no character.

Comment: What I need is for the program to run unattended without somebody typing the command. Hence I put '1' in the input.txt file. this successfully passes the first variable; but I can't get it past the 2nd part where it asks to 'press enter to continue'

Comment: If a blank line doesn't work, then we have no way to tell why not inside the program. :Probably it is polling the keyboard direct, not using standard input

Comment: Hi. I have been given the code block by the developer. Please see main box above.

Comment: That code does not relate to the entries you originally posted. I suggest you ask the developer to debug his code or explain to you why your input doesn't work. The code is not clear and is badly presented, but I can't see why you are getting what you say. Exactly which of the three messages do you get each time? Possibly a problem understanding the newline as 'legal'

Comment: Sorry, I really do not think you are undersanding what I am asking. The program expects me to type 0 [enter] ALL [enter] [enter]. I have sucessfully got the 0 and ALL. But I can't get the 2nd enter. (echo 0 & echo all) program.exe. The code now expects a '\n' to continue. I want to know how I can 'echo' this to the program also. I have tried echo. with no success. >    if( ret > 0  || str[0] == '\n' ) legal = 1;